# How can I set the range of `file.autoGuessEncoding` in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, I could set the range and order of encodings in `vimrc`. In this way, it automatically guesses the file's encoding in order.

```
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp936,gb18030,big5,euc-jp,euc-kr,latin1
```

Is this feasible in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

You can change this setting in VS Code:

```
// When enabled, will attempt to guess the character set encoding when opening files. This setting can be configured per language too.
"files.autoGuessEncoding": false,
```

But when you set it to e.g. `"ucs-bom,utf-8"`, you get a tooltip which says `Incorrect type. Expected "boolean".`

Another file-encoding related setting is this:

```
// The default character set encoding to use when reading and writing files. This setting can be configured per language too.
"files.encoding": "utf8"
```

But valid values are these (you can see these when you try to set something else):

```
"utf8", "utf8bom", "utf16le", "utf16be", "windows1252", "iso88591", "iso88593", "iso885915", "macroman", "cp437", "windows1256", "iso88596", "windows1257", "iso88594", "iso885914", "windows1250", "iso88592", "cp852", "windows1251", "cp866", "iso88595", "koi8r", "koi8u", "iso885913", "windows1253", "iso88597", "windows1255", "iso88598", "iso885910", "iso885916", "windows1254", "iso88599", "windows1258", "gbk", "gb18030", "cp950", "big5hkscs", "shiftjis", "eucjp", "euckr", "windows874", "iso885911", "koi8ru", "koi8t", "gb2312", "cp865", "cp850"
```

So no, I don't think you can do that in VS Code, at least not without extensions. (I don't know if there is such an extension which would make this possible.) But do notice that those two settings can be configured per language.

Here are relevant GitHub issues, maybe you should weigh in:

- [Allow to associate a file encoding per file path #23570](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23570)
- [Allow to configure a list of encodings to use when guessing #36951](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36951)