# VS Code keeps saving my files in UTF-8 with BOM

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, visual-studio-code, byte-order-mark

VS Code keeps saving my files in UTF-8 with BOM. My `files.encoding` setting is not set (defaults to `utf8`) in my user settings or workspace settings. `files.autoGuessEncoding` setting is also not set (defaults to `false`). After I make any edits to a file, it automatically saves it with BOM after changing it to without BOM in Notepad++. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: did you try `"files.encoding": "utf8"`?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48277776/21336