# Error message seems ambiguous without any descriptive clue

Tags: python, transcrypt

I am new to `transcrypt`. I created a test python file,`test.py`

```py
def test_def(a: list):      
    for i in range(len(a)):
        print(i)

xx = [2, 3, 4]
test_def(xx)
```

I have python 3.9. If I run the python file, it runs and prints as expected.

Running transcrypt gives following error

```
> python -m transcrypt -b -m -n .\test.py
Error while compiling (offending file last):
        File 'test', line 2, namely:

        Error while compiling (offending file last):
        File 'test', line 2, namely:


Aborted
```

I am not sure what it expects and why is it giving the error, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess (and it's only a guess) is that `transcrypt` doesn't yet support the type hints.  Remove that `: list` string and I'll bet it works.

Comment: @tim-roberts  nope, I tried both ways! same error :(

Comment: You're right, the documentation specifically states they support this.  My bad.

Comment: This is a hunch, since it would be invisible in some editors, but could your file have the byte-order mark as its first handful of characters? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Very strange.  It's something about the `range`.  If you change `range` to `xxxxx`, it compiles, but of course it won't run.

Comment: @BenY I am using VScode to edit. I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @TimRoberts bug perhaps?

Comment: I did a quick search just to see, this was the only thing I found on SO (still unanswered): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719040/vs-code-keeps-saving-my-files-in-utf-8-with-bom

Comment: @BenY I was able to reproduce what Tim observed. Changing it back to `range` brought the error back, That sort of eliminates the BOM issue, doesn't it?

Comment: If you change that line to the equivalent `for i,j in enumerate(a):` it compiles.  It doesn't correctly translate the literal list (`xx = [2, 3, 4]`) but the rest looks OK.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have bunch of large source files that have this kind `range` pattern that I wish to translate to javascript. Editing them manually could be problematic for me. I have filed a bug report in their github repo. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @kibudude Yup, was just trying to see if that could have been a possible solution. Wonder if the nesting (`range` of a `len` output) is messing things up, or just `range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Transcrypt are you using? Wasn't able to replicate the error using Python 3.9.0 and Transcrypt 3.9.0. You can check like this (Win):

```
> transcrypt -h | find "Version"
# and may as well double check that the right version of python was used:
> python --version
```

The Python and Transcrypt versions should match, as Transcrypt uses Python's AST that may change between versions.

Another aspect is that I first installed Transcrypt into a virtual env as follows (Win):

```
> py -3.9 -m venv wenv
> wenv\Source\activate.bat
> pip install transcrypt
> python -m transcrypt -b -m -n test.py
```

It sometimes happens that one inadvertently uses the wrong version of Python. 'py' is the Python launcher on Windows and useful to launch the right version if you have multiple versions installed. On Linux there are typically binaries in /usr/bin such as 'python3.9' or a symlink such as 'python3' that links to the most recent 3 version. Installing into a virtual env as demonstrated is also helpful, as various problems can come about otherwise.

The above compiled test.py without error (Win 10 cmd.exe). Fwiw, the file was saved as utf-8 and compile worked with and without a BOM.

Comment: That seems to be the problem, I do see version mismatch. Thanks so much I'll give this a try and let you know.